# Python function returns <function info at 0x7f8442e9d398>?

Tags: python, function

Hello I am having problem with my Python function. I am trying to make a simple function to return a variable and then print it. Instead it returns back **function info at 0x7f8442e9d398** instead of the string ... Any ideas ?

```
 def info():
     message = '********************************\n' \
               '*******INSTRUCTIONS*************\n' \
               '********************************\n' \
               '* This is an info message      *\n' \
               '********************************'
     return message

 print info
```

Answer (score 13):

Functions are objects in python. You are printing the representation of the function-object `info`. With this, you can use functions as any other variable, e.g. using it as a argument to another function. To call a function you need to put parens behind it

```
print info()
```

Answer (score 8):

Your function isn't returning because you're not calling it. Calling a function requires `()`:

```
print info()
```